# Prevent browser selector in an Ionic App iframe - Prevent open external browser

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using iframe for payment page in an ionic application. after clicking submit (Senden) button inside the iframe:

[image: Iframe with submit button]

A popup with browsers appear like this:

[image: The next page with "open with" browser selector]

How can I prevent this popup from appearing?

I use `targer="_self"` in the iframe. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed `allow-popups allow-top-navigation` from `sandbox` attribute of the `iframe`.

iframe before the fix:

```
<iframe #iframe id="iframe" 
        frameborder="0" 
        [src]="url"
        style="width:100%; border:none;" 
        sandbox="allow-popups allow-top-navigation allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-forms">
</iframe>
```

iframe now:

```
<iframe #iframe id="iframe" 
        frameborder="0" 
        [src]="url"
        style="width:100%; border:none;" 
        sandbox="allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-forms">
</iframe>
```

Comment: still same issue